# Resource Owner Password Grant Flow - Apache Oltu

Tags: apache, oauth-2.0, access-token, oltu

Am currently using Apache Oltu in my project for OAuth using the Authorization Grant flow. I want to migrate to Resource Owner Password Grant. Does Oltu support this? If yes, where can I see documentation/examples?

If not, what library/libraries I need to use to implement this OAuth flow?